# How does fscanf interact with the file it parses information from?

Tags: c, scanf

I am kinda new to C, have written some basic programs, but other than that I know nothing special. Currently I am writing a program that needs to get its variables from a .txt file. The .txt file is always structured like this:

```
X Y             //1st row
a1 a2 a3 a4 aX  //2nd row
```

Where the number of a's I am getting equals the number X.(Everything in the file is an int)
The bit in my code that confuses me is this:

```
fscanf(txtfile,"%d %d",&X,&Y);
    int input[X];                                                           
    for(int i=0; i<X; i++){
            fscanf(txtfile,"%d",&input[i]);
    }
```

Which works perfectly fine, but in my mind it shouldn't...
I thought that after getting X and Y from my .txt file, the fscanf in the loop would go through them again and I would have to find a way to bypass them, so they don't end up in my input[]. I was going to make a dummy array to store the first two ints and then transfer the other ones to the proper one, but it turned out that the dummy array worked just fine and the "proper" one ended with garbage in it. So what does actually happen? Does fscanf have some kind of pointer on the file that tells it where it stopped the last time it run? Or something completely different? I tried going through the man pages for fscanf, but i didn't find anything useful, or maybe it just went over my head.
P.S. The title may be a little bit off in regards to what I am asking, but I couldn't think of a better one.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: All the file input functions read from where the last one left off. You can use `fseek()` to reposition, but they don't go back to the beginning by themselves.

Comment: It would be crazy if you had to skip over everything before in order to read the next thing. I don't know where you got that idea from.

Comment: The hint is in the type of `txtfile`.

Comment: @anastaciu What does the file type have to do with it?

Comment: @Barmar It's a pointer to FILE, if you take it literaly, it's a good analogy. Maybe I'm stretching it.

Comment: Imagine the data is stored like on magnetic tape. You read one thing, and then the next in sequence (unless you fast forward or rewind). `fscanf()` used the way you have won't care about rows, only the next numeric value.

Comment: @FoolingAround Not really. The `FILE` pointer is a pointer to a data structure that has information about the file you're reading, it's not a pointer into the file data itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does fscanf have some kind of pointer on the file that tells it where it stopped the last time it run?

Close.  The `FILE` object that `txtfile` points to stores the current file position, which gets updated after each successful read (or write, if it's an output stream) operation.  If you find that need to go back and re-read an earlier input item, then you'll need to reset that file position using the `fseek` or `rewind` library functions.

I/O in C is hidden behind abstractions known as *streams* - as far as your program is concerned, a stream is just a producer (or consumer) of bytes.  Each time you successfully read from a stream you "remove" those bytes from the stream<sup>1</sup>, so you're not constantly re-reading the same data over and over again.

---

1. Logically speaking - the contents of the underlying file are not altered.